# Удаление из строки символов, чьи индексы делятся на 3 без остатка

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

**Вот задание**. Дана строка. Удалите из нее все символы, чьи индексы делятся на 3. Символы строки нумеруются, начиная с нуля.
**Вот код.**

```
s = str(input())
pos = 0
v = 0
while v != -1:
    v = s.find('', pos)
    k = s[v]
    if v % 3 == 0:
        s = s.replace(k, '')
    pos += 1
print(s)
```

**Вот ошибка.**

> ```
> k = s[v].
> IndexError: string index out of range.
> ```

Объясните, пожалуйста, что не так с кодом?

Comment: на вопрос что не так с вашим кодом вам ответят другие участники SO. Я бы вам посоветовал сразу привыкать к хорошему стилю: `s = ''.join(x for i,x in enumerate(s) if i%3)` ;)

Comment: А вы сделайте `print(v, repr(s))` перед проблемной строкой

Comment: Чему, по-вашему, будет равно v после v=s.find('', pos)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых, команда

```
v = s.find('', pos)
```

делает то-же самое, как просто

```
v = pos if pos <= len(s) else -1
```

Уже здесь проблема - когда ваша строка `s` будет например `"abc"`, может настать случай, когда `v == 3`, а команда `k = s[v]` превратится в `k = s[3]` - *ошибка, т.к. `s[3]` не существует*.

Во вторых, командой

```
s = s.replace(k, '')
```

ваша исходная строка `s` *постепенно сокращается*, значит, очередная третья позиция (для удаления символа) *не будет той-же самой, как в исходной строке*.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = list(input())
del s[::3]
print(''.join(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
s = input()
print(''.join(s[i] for i in range(len(s)) if i % 3 != 0))
```

Comment: Кст, а мб добавить пример с enumerate? `print(''.join(c for i, c in enumerate(s) if i % 3 != 0))`? Для случаев, когда нужны и индексы, и значения сразу, он лучше подходит чем range :)

Comment: @gil9red, почему-бы и нет. Хотя кто мешает использовать `i, s[i]`?